# Error al agregar controlador en .net

Tags: c#, .net, mvc

Cuando le doy agregar controlador a la carpeta controllers y selecciono el controlador, me aparece este mensaje.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y ya intentaste arreglar la referencia a la **`dll`** `AccesoDatos`?

Comment: estas agregando un controller vacio o con un template que usa datos de la persistencia, quizas tomandolo del mapping de entity framework

Comment: Antes de agregar un controlador nuevo debes realizar un `Rebuild` o un `Volver a generar`  tu aplicación.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Leandro, ¿nos podrías mostrar de qué manera agregas el controlador? Es decir, las opciones que le pones en la ventana anterior al error